# GoogleApiClient: hide GPS icon on status bar when a service is in the background

Tags: android, android-service, google-api-client, android-gps, android-googleapiclient

I'm using GoogleApiClient to implement a location listener service, but the GPS icon is always being displayed, even with the service in background. How to disable the GPS icon when the service is in the background?

[image]

Follow the sources below:

**Activity**

```
public class ShowDistanceActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ILocationConstants {

protected static final String TAG = ShowDistanceActivity.class.getSimpleName();


@Bind(R.id.tvLocationData)
TextView tvLocationData;

@Bind(R.id.toolbar)
Toolbar toolbar;


/**
 * Receiver listening to Location updates and updating UI in activity
 */
private LocationReceiver locationReceiver;

/**
 * Permission util with callback mechanism to avoid boilerplate code
 * <p/>
 * https://github.com/kayvannj/PermissionUtil
 */
private PermissionUtil.PermissionRequestObject mBothPermissionRequest;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_distance);

    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    locationReceiver = new LocationReceiver();


}


private void startLocationService() {

    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, LocationService.class);
    startService(serviceIntent);

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(locationReceiver, new IntentFilter(LOACTION_ACTION));


    /**
     * Runtime permissions are required on Android M and above to access User's location
     */
    if (AppUtils.hasM() && !(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

        askPermissions();

    } else {

        startLocationService();

    }

}

/**
 * Ask user for permissions to access GPS location on Android M
 */
public void askPermissions() {

    mBothPermissionRequest =
            PermissionUtil.with(this).request(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION).onResult(
                    new Func2() {
                        @Override
                        protected void call(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

                            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                                startLocationService();

                            } else {

                                Toast.makeText(ShowDistanceActivity.this, R.string.permission_denied, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }

                    }).ask(PERMISSION_ACCESS_LOCATION_CODE);

}


@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(locationReceiver);
}

private class LocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        if (null != intent && intent.getAction().equals(LOACTION_ACTION)) {

            String locationData = intent.getStringExtra(LOCATION_MESSAGE);

            tvLocationData.setText(locationData);
        }

    }
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

    if (null != mBothPermissionRequest) {
        mBothPermissionRequest.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

}

**Service**

```
public class LocationService extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener, ILocationConstants, IPreferenceConstants {


private static final String TAG = LocationService.class.getSimpleName();

/**
 * Provides the entry point to Google Play services.
 */
protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

/**
 * Stores parameters for requests to the FusedLocationProviderApi.
 */
protected LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

/**
 * Represents a geographical location.
 */
protected Location mCurrentLocation;


private String mLatitudeLabel;
private String mLongitudeLabel;
private String mLastUpdateTimeLabel;
private String mDistance;


/**
 * Time when the location was updated represented as a String.
 */
protected String mLastUpdateTime;

private Location oldLocation;

private Location newLocation;


private AppPreferences appPreferences;

/**
 * Total distance covered
 */
private float distance;


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate() called");

    appPreferences = new AppPreferences(this);

    oldLocation = new Location("Point A");
    newLocation = new Location("Point B");

    mLatitudeLabel = getString(R.string.latitude_label);
    mLongitudeLabel = getString(R.string.longitude_label);
    mLastUpdateTimeLabel = getString(R.string.last_update_time_label);
    mDistance = getString(R.string.distance);

    mLastUpdateTime = "";

    distance = appPreferences.getFloat(PREF_DISTANCE, 0);

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate Distance: " + distance);


}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand called");

    buildGoogleApiClient();

    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        startLocationUpdates();
    }

    return Service.START_STICKY;

}


/**
 * Builds a GoogleApiClient. Uses the {@code #addApi} method to request the
 * LocationServices API.
 */
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {

    Log.d(TAG, "buildGoogleApiClient() called");

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    createLocationRequest();
}


protected void createLocationRequest() {

    Log.d(TAG, "createLocationRequest() called");

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();

    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);
}

/**
 * Requests location updates from the FusedLocationApi.
 */
protected void startLocationUpdates() {

    try {

        Log.d(TAG, "startLocationUpdates called");

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

    } catch (SecurityException ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}


/**
 * Updates the latitude, the longitude, and the last location time in the UI.
 */
private void updateUI() {

    if (null != mCurrentLocation) {

        StringBuilder sbLocationData = new StringBuilder();
        sbLocationData.append(mLatitudeLabel)
                .append(" ")
                .append(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude())
                .append("\n")
                .append(mLongitudeLabel)
                .append(" ")
                .append(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude())
                .append("\n")
                .append(mLastUpdateTimeLabel)
                .append(" ")
                .append(mLastUpdateTime)
                .append("\n")
                .append(mDistance)
                .append(" ")
                .append(getUpdatedDistance())
                .append(" meters");


        /*
         * update preference with latest value of distance
         */
        appPreferences.putFloat(PREF_DISTANCE, distance);

        Log.d(TAG, "Location Data:\n" + sbLocationData.toString());

        sendLocationBroadcast(sbLocationData.toString());
    } else {

        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.unable_to_find_location, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}


/**
 * Send broadcast using LocalBroadcastManager to update UI in activity
 *
 * @param sbLocationData
 */
private void sendLocationBroadcast(String sbLocationData) {

    Log.d(TAG, "sendLocationBroadcast() called");

    Intent locationIntent = new Intent();
    locationIntent.setAction(LOACTION_ACTION);
    locationIntent.putExtra(LOCATION_MESSAGE, sbLocationData);

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(locationIntent);

}

/**
 * Removes location updates from the FusedLocationApi.
 */
protected void stopLocationUpdates() {

    Log.d(TAG, "stopLocationUpdates() called");

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy() called");

    appPreferences.putFloat(PREF_DISTANCE, distance);

    stopLocationUpdates();

    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();

    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy Distance " + distance);

    super.onDestroy();
}


/**
 * Runs when a GoogleApiClient object successfully connects.
 */
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) throws SecurityException {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GoogleApiClient");


    if (mCurrentLocation == null) {
        mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        updateUI();
    }

    startLocationUpdates();

}

/**
 * Callback that fires when the location changes.
 */
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged() called");

    mCurrentLocation = location;
    mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    updateUI();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {

    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended() called");

    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {

    Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + result.getErrorCode());
}


private float getUpdatedDistance() {

    /**
     * There is 68% chance that user is with in 100m from this location.
     * So neglect location updates with poor accuracy
     */


    if (mCurrentLocation.getAccuracy() > ACCURACY_THRESHOLD) {

        Log.d(TAG, "getUpdatedDistance() called");

        return distance;
    }


    if (oldLocation.getLatitude() == 0 && oldLocation.getLongitude() == 0) {

        oldLocation.setLatitude(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude());
        oldLocation.setLongitude(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());

        newLocation.setLatitude(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude());
        newLocation.setLongitude(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());

        return distance;
    } else {

        oldLocation.setLatitude(newLocation.getLatitude());
        oldLocation.setLongitude(newLocation.getLongitude());

        newLocation.setLatitude(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude());
        newLocation.setLongitude(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());

    }


    /**
     * Calculate distance between last two geo locations
     */
    distance += newLocation.distanceTo(oldLocation);

    return distance;
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
```

}

**Manifest**

Android Manifest declaration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.technosavy.showmedistance">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".ShowDistanceActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <service
            android:name=".service.LocationService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"></service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please, any help is welcome.

Comment: I believe this is a security feature and can not be hidden. Happy to corrected, but this is what I understand.

Comment: Hi Tigger! Some apps trigger our location and this icon is not displayed :(

Comment: They are using the permission setting of `android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` with `PRIORITY_NO_POWER` or `PRIORITY_LOW_POWER`. Which is fine if you only need a rough location to the users location. This will return the users cached location only. I'll write a correct answer if needed.

Comment: @Tigger, please, i'm stuck on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the GPS icon you need to use cached and wi-fi location settings (from memory). In your code make the following changes.

In Manifest, **remove**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

In Service, change the following:

```
mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000L);
mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000L);
// Do NOT use LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY here
// Instead use one of the other option.
mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
//mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_LOW_POWER);
//mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_NO_POWER);
// Remove setSmallestDisplacement() as it should not be used
// unless you are using a GPS / PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
//mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);
```

Pretty sure this is will remove the GPS icon but you will also only get the `FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation()` values when the `onConnected()` method is called (very possible this will be low accuracy).

The `onLocationChanged()` method *may* never trigger until another application makes a location request at a higher priority or with more accuracy.

Comment: Tnx a lot, i was 2 days stuck on it

Comment: Happy to help, but remember the location accuracy can be way off with these settings.

Answer (score 1):

The new fused location providers take a slightly different approach compared to previous methods. Developers now choose how much battery power is used to calculate a location instead of which device components are used to calculate it. It uses any available combination of GPS, Wi-Fi, mobile networks, and onboard sensors to calculate the location.

The LocationRequest priority settings are now:

PRIORITY_NO_POWER (passively listens for location updates from other clients)
PRIORITY_LOW_POWER (~10km "city" accuracy)
PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY (~100m "block" accuracy)
PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY (accurate as possible at the expense of battery life)
Google describes the LocationRequest class here: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html